# Ubuntu unity launcher numbers to be always shown

Tags: unity, launcher, keyboard-accelerators

When I hold the 'super' key on my keyboard, it shows me numbers over the launcher icons so the super+number combination would jump to the application. I tend to forget numbers, and holding the 'super' key each time to display it is delaying my swtich operation. I would like something like a permanent number over the icon, so always visible. That way I would always know which super+number combination opens which application. Is such a thing possible or there are some other keyaboard centric way to switch between applications, besides alt+tab of course?

Comment: what is for you the most important downside of alt_tab?

Comment: If I have many apps open, I need to hit alt tab too many times to switch between them

Comment: @Sava have you found how to do that?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem and was hoping to find an answer in this thread, but didn't.  My current solution:  physically tape little pieces of paper with numbers on them on the monitor bezel next to the launcher buttons.  I assume you were looking for an electronic solution, but what's the difference?

As an added benefit, if you have any passwords you need to write down, now you've got sticky notes on your monitor to use! ;)

Seriously though, get some paper and tape and you're all set.

Comment: interesting, however I see it more as a desktop than a laptop solution

Comment: @Sava Yeah, agreed.