# Permanently show taskbar (Ubuntu Dock) numbers

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I use the <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>*number*</kbd> hotkeys a lot to switch windows. I've noticed if I hold down <kbd>super</kbd> and a <kbd>*number*</kbd>-key I can see what each applications number is. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576990/ubuntu-unity-launcher-numbers-to-be-always-shown) asks for the same thing, but I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1, so things may have become possible since then. Pictured is what I want to be permanent:

[image: holding down super and a number]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's currently possible (without any ugly hacks) to display the numbers permanently. But you can make them appear in a '*passive*' way (i.e. just shows the numbers instead of switching to or launching the associated application) by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> instead of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>*number*</kbd>.

Comment: Indeed, I also do not think it is currently possible in Dash-to-dock. Also here, Dash-to-panel has an edge:  there, one can set the numbers to display permanently.

Comment: @vanadium what do you mean "one can set the numbers to display permanently" in  "Dash-to-panel"?

Comment: Dash-to-panel is a different extension. It features the possibility to display these numbers permanently, in contrast to Dash to Dock (and Ubuntu Dock, which is based on Dash to Dock).

Comment: This does not seem to work for 19.10. Can anyone confirm this, or have I screwed something up?